# Add twitter bootstrap icon to linkRoute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, icons, laravel-blade

Wondering how to add a icon to a Linkroute.

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('edit_data', 'Edit', $data->id) }}
```

I want the edit to show:

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
```

I tried this, but that didn't work:

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('edit_data', '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>', $data->id) }}
```

Comment: That should work - what exact HTML are you getting?

Comment: That shouldn't work, because the '<span....' string is processed by htmlentities. I suggest defining a helper function for this one.

Comment: Use a macro custom macro instead.

Comment: @deczo my bad. I could've sworn I've done it this way before and it's worked. Must be thinking of something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work , you can use `HTML` tags instead of this function or create a [custom macro](http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros) like this:

```
HTML::macro('iLinkRoute', function($name, $title = null, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array(), $html = ''){
    $url = route($name, $parameters);
    if (is_null($title) || $title === false) $title = $url;
    return "<a href = '$url'>$html.$title</a>" ;
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
{{ HTML::iLinkRoute('user.show.profile', 'Profile', ['username' => 'heera'], [] , '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>') }}
```

The generated output:

```
<a href="http://blog.dev/user/heera"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>.Profile</a>
```

You may keep the `macro` in your `filters.php` or create a file as `macros.php` and add this file using `require` within `app/starts/global.php` file, just add the require at the end of `global.php`:

```
require '/macros.php';
```

Comment: Is it not a easier way to do it ? What looked very heavy.

Comment: I suppose the easier way, as the answerer suggested, is using bare html: `<a href="{{{ URL::route('edit_data', array($data->id)) }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using controllers, then you could use the action helper function; like:

```
<a href={{ action('HomeController@showHome', $params) }}>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the URL::route()

`<a href="{{URL::route('edit_data', array($data->id))}}">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Text
</a>`